# How to place multiple linearlayout in custom dialogs?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I created a custom dialog with radio buttons that are populated on runtime. If no of radio button exceed 12, the bottom linearlayout(with buttons) does not show. How can I solve this? My Code

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:padding = "16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "100dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_radiogroup"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"></RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_custom_cancel_button"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight = "4dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text = "Cancel" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_custom_ok_button"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "4dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text = "Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: don't use this , rather use a recyclerview

Comment: srcollView would be a nicer choice instead of recyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinearLayout that wraps your ScrollView is set to "wrap_content" in height which pushes your buttons out of screen the bigger your list gets.

I'd suggest to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), which allows you to position your views relative to each other. For example "buttons always aligned on bottom of parent, ScrollView always above buttons and below parent's top"

Comment: ConstraintLayout will fix some of these problems, but really this should be a recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your parent LinearLayout to FrameLayout and set Bottom container (LinearLayout) gravity to Bottom

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width = "match_parent"
     android:layout_height = "match_parent"
     android:padding = "16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "100dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_radiogroup"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"></RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation = "horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_custom_cancel_button"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight = "4dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text = "Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/input_radio_button_custom_ok_button"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "4dp"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:text = "Ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```